# VS Code GUI is just black boxes all over

Tags: ubuntu, user-interface, visual-studio-code

I had an openssl issue and I had to remove it from ubuntu and reinstall it.  I did that and it worked fine, I've had no other issues with other programs since then.  I then noticed that vs code started to look like the screen shot below:

[image: vs code image]

I have tried reinstall in vscode, and ubuntu-desktop and the issue persists with no changes.  I believe this issue was created because of a missing dependency of sorts when I removed and OpenSSL and that dependency was never properly restored.

An accepted solution would be my GUI looking normal again in VS Code without reinstalling the Ubuntu OS itself.

Answer (score 0):

It's funny how asking a question can turn you to a solution.

I started going through the logs for vs code in `~/.config/Code/logs/*` and noticed some missing javascript files causing errors.  There were several files causing issues.  To resolve this issue I preformed the following steps:

1. Uninstalled vscode again using `snap remove code`
2. Removed the folder `~/.config/Code`
3. Removed the folder `~/.vscode`
4. Installed vscode using `snap install code`
5. Issue resolved.

Comment: please see the answer in the duplicate target. what you did happened to work because you nuked the thing that solves the problem when you nuke it in addition to nuking a bunch of other stuff that you didn't need to nuke and that most people would probably not want to nuke.